# Does Spiritual Weapon ignore cover?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, cover

A tree is between me and the enemy. It provides half cover to an enemy.

**If I cast Spiritual Weapon adjacent to him, does Spiritual Weapon ignore the cover provided by the tree?** Or, because my line of sight is half-blocked by the tree, does the half-cover bonus stay?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### Spiritual Weapon ignores Cover (but not Visibility) between the Caster and Target

The [Cover](http://5e.d20srd.org/srd/combat/Cover.htm) rules state:

> A target can benefit from cover only when an attack or other effect originates on the opposite side of the cover

[Spiritual Weapon](http://5e.d20srd.org/srd/spells/spiritualWeapon.htm) indicates that the weapon itself is attacking the Target, so only Cover between the Weapon and the Target matters.

However: [Visibility](http://5e.d20srd.org/srd/theEnvironment.htm) is still determined based on the Caster to Target. This is supported by [Jeremy Crawford's statements](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2014/12/05/spiritual-weapon/):

> The spell doesn't require you to see its target. It follows the normal rules for attacking a target you can't see.
>
> *Questioner: caster could leave the room and leave a spiritual weapon floating in the doorway for a minute w/ disadv to hit?*
>
> Crawford: Yes, assuming there's actually something there to hit.

Comment: You might link the 2017 SageAdvice. Also, the Podcast from Feb 12, 2017 he explicitly goes into detail about this spell and its interaction with cover.

Comment: @Slagmoth do you have a link for the more recent sage advice reference? My search-fu is poor.

Comment: @Carcer Actually it was my mistake I thought he was referencing the [Compendium](http://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf) but was referencing the SageAdvice.eu... also the Podcast can be found [here](http://dnd.wizards.com/dragon-talk/podcast-hub). I can't seem to get a direct link for some reason. But it is the Jan 19, 2017 podcast, filter by Crawford to shorten the list.